# get json values depending on specific child value

Tags: json, xcode, uitableview, swift4

how i can get values depending on value in child node. For example 
if i have JSON like this

```
      {
          "id": 14,
          "name": "АBC",
          "picture": 44,
          "group": {
              "id": 2,
              "gname": "AAA",
              "pic": 1
          }
     },
      {
          "id": 14,
          "name": "АBC",
          "picture": 44,
          "group": {
              "id": 1,
              "gname": "BB",
              "pic": 2
          }
      }...
]
```

i want to get list of all names where child value is "AAA"

I know how to read all values for name but i don't know how to read them if i want only names who have specific gname value.

Here is code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ThirdViewController : UITableViewController {

    var dataInfo = [[String: AnyObject]]()
    let url = "http://XXX"
    let header = ["X": "XXX"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.rowHeight = 50
        getData(url: url)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataInfo.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! Cell2
        cell.lblName?.text = dataInfo[indexPath.row]["name"] as? String
        return cell
    }
    func getData(url: String) {
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, headers: header)
            .responseJSON { response in
                if response.result.isSuccess {
                    print("Sucess! Got the data")
                    let dataJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                    self.updateData(json: dataJSON)

                } else {
                    print("Error: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    func updateData(json : JSON) {
        if let data = json[].arrayObject {
            self.dataInfo = data as! [[String: AnyObject]]
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        else {
            print("cannot connect to the server")
        }
    }

}
```

I would be grateful if someone can help me.

Comment: Unrelated but the lines `self.tableView.reloadData()` at the end of `viewDidLoad()` and `getData(` are pointless because `dataInfo` is empty when the function is called. You are encouraged to use `Codable` to decode the data. `SwiftyJSON` is outdated since Swift 4.

Comment: Thank you for info sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First you should use `Codable` instead of `SwiftyJSON`

So you have to add these models

```
struct Group: Codable {
    var id: Int?
    var gname: String?
    var pic: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, gname, pic
    }
}

struct User: Codable {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
    var picture: Int?
    var group: Group?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, picture, group
    }
}
```

And Now you have to add this to `Alamofire.request`

```
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()

let dataJSON = try? jsonDecoder.decode([User].self, from: response.data!)
```

An now to the filter Thing, if you only need element with "AAA" we can filter the array like

```
let users: [User] = []

let searchString = "AAA"

let filterResults = users.filter({
    $0.group.filter({$0.gname == searchString}).count > 1
})
```

So you whole code will look like

```
class ThirdViewController : UITableViewController {

    var dataInfo: [User] = []

    let url = "http://XXX"
    let header = ["X": "XXX"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.rowHeight = 50

        getData(url: url)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataInfo.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! Cell2
        cell.lblName?.text = dataInfo[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }

    func getData(url: String) {
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, headers: header)
            .responseJSON { response in
                if response.result.isSuccess {
                    print("Sucess! Got the data")

                    guard let responseData = response.data else {
                      print("didn't get any data from API")
                      return
                    }

                    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let dataJSON = try? jsonDecoder.decode([User].self, from: responseData)

                    // Search data
                    let searchString = "AAA"

                    let filterResults = users.filter({
                        $0.group.gname == searchString
                    })

                    self.dataInfo = filterResults

                    // Reload Data
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                } else {
                    print("Error: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir Razi now i have error for converting 
[link](https://imgur.com/iupwq2m) - "cannot convert value of type 'Any'  to expected argument type 'Data' " ... and if i convert it as Data i get this
[link](https://imgur.com/T3aMiOW) - "Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x1d13f6a70) to 'NSData' (0x1d13f4dd8)."

Comment: @StefanSimić It was a silly mistake at my end, i've edited the post with the said fix, hope this was the answer you needed.

Comment: @Sir Razi it's ok, but as result property filterResults give me an empty array.

Comment: Ah i found mistake, it's ok now. Ty for help sir.